# Conditional grouping of a dataframe

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have a data frame containing two columns indexed as name and age, now I want to group these data based on age range such as 11-20 years, 21-30  years and so on.
My thought process: add a new column and assign value based on a condition fulfilling the age range and then groupby based on newly assigned value. However, I am not able to code such thought. I am new to python. Can anyone help me? any other technique to do that is also welcome. The final aim is to classify data in age bracket and perform exploratory analysis.

Here is my code:

```
dic_1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ram','shyam','mohan', 'kalpesh', 'suresh'], 
'Age' : [15,30,40,50,60]})
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dic_1)
df_1 ['group'] = np.array(np.random.randn(len(df_1['Age'])))
df_1.loc[df_1['Age'] < 20, 'group'] = "below twenty"
df_1.loc[20 <= df_1['Age'] < 30, 'group'] = "twenty to thrity"
df_1.loc[30 <= df_1['Age'] < 40, 'group'] = "thrity to forty"
df_1.loc[df_1['Age'] > 40, 'group'] = "above forty"
print (df_1)
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2225619)

Comment: Perhaps duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316631/series-of-if-statements-applied-to-data-frame